# pandas replace dataframe float values using int keys of nested dict

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe and dictionary like as shown below

```
ID,Name,value,total,     
1,Ajay,2.00,35          
1,Dan,3.00,65
2,Ajay,2,78
2,Rajini,0.0,98           
3,Ajay,3.00,53    
3,Rad,75.25,21

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

output = {'Ajay': {1: 'ABC', 2: 'DEF', 3: 'DUMMA', 4: 'CHUMMA'}, 'Dan': {0: 'KOREA', 1: 'AUS/NZ', 2: 'INDIA', 3: 'ASEAN'}}
```

I would like to do the below

a) Replace the values in `value` column by matching `Name` value to `Name` key in nested dict.

For ex: `ID=1` has Name as `Ajay` and value as `2.00`.

Now, if we look at the dict, we `Ajay` outer key and trying to find the matching key (which is `2`). So, we replace value `2.00` with `DEF`.

Similarly, we do this for other Name which is `Dan`.

I tried the below

```
df1.replace({"values": output},inplace=True)  # doesn't work
for d in output.values():
    print(d.key())
```

Is there any efficient and elegant way to do this sort of replacement for million rows dataframe?

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for new column and then use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace not matched values by `value` column:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(output).stack().rename('new'), on=['value','Name'])
df['value'] = df.pop('new').fillna(df['value'])
print (df)
   ID    Name  value  total
0   1    Ajay    DEF     35
1   1     Dan  ASEAN     65
2   2    Ajay    DEF     78
3   2  Rajini    0.0     98
4   3    Ajay  DUMMA     53
5   3     Rad  75.25     21
```

Comment: How are you able to do `join` when there is no common column between `df` and `dataframe(dict)`?

Comment: `value` and `name` keys come from `df` dataframe but they are not available in `pd.DataFrame(output)`. So, how is join happenning?

Comment: @TheGreat -because is used `stack` - it create `MultiIndex` from columns and index in `pd.DataFrame(output)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```py
# map value-Names to output and fill the missing values with original values
df1['value'] = pd.Series(df1.set_index(['value','Name']).index.map(pd.DataFrame(output).stack())).fillna(df1['value'])
print(df1)
```

```
   ID    Name  value  total
0   1    Ajay    DEF     35
1   1     Dan  ASEAN     65
2   2    Ajay    DEF     78
3   2  Rajini    0.0     98
4   3    Ajay  DUMMA     53
5   3     Rad  75.25     21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try loop the dictionary then use `df.mask` or `np.where` or `loc` with boolean indexing to replace value.

```py
for k, v in output.items():
    df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df['Name'].eq(k), df['value'].map(v))
    #df['value'] = np.where(df['Name'].eq(k), df['value'].map(v), df['value'])
    #df.loc[df['Name'].eq(k), 'value'] = df.loc[df['Name'].eq(k), 'value'].map(v)
```

```
print(df)

   ID    Name  value  total
0   1    Ajay    DEF     35
1   1     Dan  ASEAN     65
2   2    Ajay    DEF     78
3   2  Rajini    0.0     98
4   3    Ajay  DUMMA     53
5   3     Rad  75.25     21
```